# the meaning of "ring" in Serge Lang's "Algebraic Number Theory"

Tags: algebraic-number-theory

On p. 3 of Serge Lang's "Algebraic Number Theory" where he is attempting to define localization he writes "Let $A$ be a ring... Let $K$ be the quotient field of $A$...". Does this mean that he is using "ring" to mean "integral domain"?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Certainly "ring" does not mean integral domain in general. 
For the *localization* $S^{-1}A$ with a multiplicatively closed subset $S\subseteq A$ one need not assume that $A$ is an integral ring. However, for the quotient field we must assume that $A$ is an integral domain.

Edit: Now that I have the book here, I found what Lang means. On page $vii$ in the Prerequisites he says explicitly:

The word **ring** will always mean commutative ring without zero divisors and with unit element - in other words, it means integral domain.

Comment: He says $A$ is a ring and then goes on to say that $S$ is a multiplicatively closed subset of $A$ which contains 1 and not 0. So in particular $A$ is not the zero ring.

Can any meaning to the notion of quotient field of $A$ be given in that context. Should I just assume it is an error?

Comment: For a quotient field you necessarily need that $A$ has no zero divisors. I think, it is not an error, but just an abbreviation for him.